# EDUP EP-DB1607 Driver Installation help request

Tags: 17.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 x64 (final beta), but I am unable to install the EDUP driver I need for my device ([EDUP Driver](http://www.szedup.com/support/driver-download/ep-db1607-driver/)).

I am not a fan of Unity, but not a hater, either. But I do enjoy Gnome, hence my reason to upgrade. That aside, my output for uname -r and lsusb are below:

uname -r
`4.13.0-12-generic`

lsusb
`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 20f4:624d TRENDnet
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 1908:0226 GEMBIRD`

The TRENDnet is for my TRENDnet TEW-624UB that has always worked with Linux. The problem is, over the past few months it overheats within minutes of being used and shuts off to cool. I can get only a few minutes out of it at a time, thus why I upgraded to the EDUP dongle.

Looking on posts and such I can't find if this is supported for Linux 4.13, and the CD definitely doesn't help. I tried finding some files on Github with no luck. I do not know what else to do. Can anyone direct me to a resolve to this? I would love to get this dongle working if at all possible.

-C

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 x64 `4.4.0-131-generic` same issue